# WPF XAML Resource Object Is Only Visible Once

Tags: wpf, binding, resources, styles, controltemplate

Trying for hours without success and would love to understand why only one of three buttons show the icon ViewBox content.

I think I don't understand the inner workings of control templates enough.

The first file ButtonProperties class is the owner of the attached property which holds the Icon ViewBox.
The second file is my MainWindow.xaml Window which should show 3 buttons with the Viewbox Icon. But only the last button instance shows the Viewbox Icon.

Thanks for any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ButtonProperties : DependencyObject
    { 

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconViewboxProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IconViewbox",
            typeof(Viewbox), typeof(ButtonProperties), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static void SetIconViewbox(DependencyObject obj, Viewbox viewbox)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IconViewboxProperty, viewbox);
        }

        public static Viewbox GetIconViewbox(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Viewbox) obj.GetValue(IconViewboxProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Viewbox x:Key="IconTrash">
                <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                    <Path Data="M19,4H15.5L14.5,3H9.5L8.5,4H5V6H19M6,19A2,2 0 0,0 8,21H16A2,2 0 0,0 18,19V7H6V19Z" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" />
                </Canvas>
            </Viewbox>

            <Style x:Key="ButtonIcon" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentControl x:Name="IconControl" Content="{Binding Path=(local:ButtonProperties.IconViewbox), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="IconControl" Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style
                x:Key="ButtonIconTrash"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonIcon}"
                TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="local:ButtonProperties.IconViewbox" Value="{DynamicResource IconTrash}" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonIconTrash}" />
        <Button
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonIconTrash}" />
        <Button
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            Style="{DynamicResource ButtonIconTrash}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default all resources are shared. Usually the XAML processor creates an instance of the defined resource e.g., a `DataTemplate` and reuses it. But if the resource is directly added to the object graph and since the XAML processor by default always creates a single instance of the resource and shares it throughout the scope, the instance can only be part of the XAML object graph once.
In other words, an instance of `Visual` that is directly added to the object graph (visual tree or in case of `FrameworkElement` also the logical tree) can't be in multiple places in this graph simultaneously.

You must disable sharing explicitly by setting `x:Shared` attribute to `false` on the element. This forces the XAML processor to create a new instance of the resource for each ocurrence in the object graph:

```
<Viewbox x:Key="IconTrash" x:Shared="False">
  <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
    <Path Data="M19,4H15.5L14.5,3H9.5L8.5,4H5V6H19M6,19A2,2 0 0,0 8,21H16A2,2 0 0,0 18,19V7H6V19Z" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" />
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Take good care of them. At least save a few strands of hair for the serious problems. Generally a handful somewhere on your head is recommended.